# Getting total number of likes that user received by going through all his/her posts MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mern, mongodb-atlas

I'm currently using MERN stack to create a simple SNS application.

However I got stuck trying to come up with a query that could go through all of the post that user posted and get the sum of likes.

Currently I've created 3 Schemas. User, Post, Reply.

### **User**

```
  const userSchema = new Schema({
  
   facebookId: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
  },

  username: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
  },

  joined: Date
})
```

### **POST**

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  datePosted: Date,
  reply: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Reply'}],
  tag: [ {type: String} ]

});
```

### **REPLY**

```
 const replySchema = new Schema({
      title: String,
      body: String,
      author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
      datePosted: Date,
      post: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}],
      likes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }] // storing likes as array 
    });
```

As you can see I have added **likes** field in Reply Schema as an array that takes in User ObjectId.
Say some user has posted 4 replies and each of them received 1 ,3, 4, 5 likes respectively. In the leaderboard section I want to display user info with the total number of counts that they received from all of their replies which is 1+3+4+5 = 13 likes.

**Can this be achieved without adding additional fields or is there a better way of structuring the schema.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this field is going to be shown publicly then I personally recommend that instead of calculating on the fly you pre-calculate it and save it on the user as aggregating data is expensive and should not be a part of your app's logic, especially if this needs to be calculated for each user for the `leaderboard` feature.

With this said here is how you can calculate it with the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)

```
db.replies.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            author: userid
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            likes: {$sum: {$size: '$likes'}}
        }
    }
]);
```

As I said I recommend you do this offline, run this once for each user and save a `likeCount` field on the user, you can then update your other routes where a like is created to update the user like count using [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

```
// .. new like created ...
db.users.updateOne({_id: liked_reply.author}, {$inc: {likeCount: 1}})
```

And now finding the leaderboard is super easy:

```
const leaders = await db.users.find({}).sort({likeCount: -1}).limit(10) //top 10?
```

Comment: thanks. so everytime someone press a like button, i just have to add the user id in the reply array + update the user like Count using the following query right? db.users.updateOne({_id: liked_reply.author}, {$inc: {likeCount: 1}}

Comment: Yes that is correct, the small downside of pre-processing

Answer (score 0):

you can use the models aggregate function to do that:

```js
const userid = 1234

post.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: userid } },
  { $lookup: {
    from: 'Reply',
    localField: 'reply',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'replies'
  } },
  { $group: {
    _id: false,
    sumoflikes: { $sum: '$replies.likes' }
  } }
])
```

the structure works as follows:

1. get all the posts from a user with 'userid'
2. join the table with 'Reply'
3. sum all of the reply.likes

(it could be that you need to throw in a $unwind: '$replies between 2 and 3 there, i am not 100% certain)